# Integrating Question: $\int \frac{\cos^2x}{1+\sin x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

## Question:

Find the value of the following expression:

$$\int \frac{\cos^2x}{1+\sin x}\ dx$$

## My Working:

### Failed Method 1:

Basically, I first tried to use $u$-substitution with $u=1+\sin x$, and this would result in

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx}&=\cos x\\
du&=\cos x\cdot dx
\end{align}

This would not cancel out the other $\cos x$.

### Failed Method 2:

I also tried using the formula $$\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos2x}{2},$$ but that would result in  the integral being equivalent to

\begin{align}
& \quad\int\frac{\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}}{1+\sin x}\ dx\\
&=\int\frac{1+\cos2x}{2+2\sin x}\ dx
\end{align}

Nothing would cancel out here either.

## WolframAlpha's Answer Which Looks Ridiculous:

I've also tried using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bcosx%2C2%5D%2C1%2Bsinx%5D%2Cx%5D), but the "answer", shown below, looks terrifying, and maybe not the right answer (at least, not the simplified right answer). (By the way, I don't have WolframAlpha Pro, so I cannot access the step-by-step solution)

$$-\frac{\left[2 \sqrt{1 - \sin x} \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 - \sin x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + (\sin x - 1) \sqrt{\sin x + 1}\right] \cos^3x}{(\sin x - 1)^2 (\sin x + 1)^{3/2}} + c$$

### Could you please give me some advice on how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did Wolfram Alpha really produce that?

$\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2x=(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)$.

You can do the rest yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem now. I just forgot to use the theorem. +1, will accept soon.

Comment: I don't understand why but I got the same result: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%5E2x%7D%7B1%2B%5Csin+x%7D+dx But look at this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%5E2x%7D%7B1%2B%5Csin+x%7D

Comment: The lesson being: WolframAlpha isn't infallible.

Comment: @PrincessEev Yes, I remember when it couldn't factor $x^4+y^4$ without going to complex numbers.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Very strange. I reported this as a bug.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\int {\cos^2 x  \over 1+\sin x   } \mathrm{d}x&=
\int {1-\sin^2 x  \over 1 + \sin x } \mathrm{d}x
\\&=\int {(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x) \over (1+\sin x) } \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int (1-\sin x) \mathrm d x\\&=x+\cos x + \mathrm{const}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wait wait, why I was downvoted?

Comment: Sorry, probably because you answered a little late. But you still provided more working out, so I upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "tan half-ange" substitution, $viz$ $$u=\tan (x/2)$$ to convert the integral to the integral of a rational function.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$. Then $I=\int (1-\sin x) dx$